# Symbol's definition is void: org-back-to-heading-or-point-min

Tags: org-mode

Package `org-id` and `org-attach` uses a function `org-back-to-heading-or-point-min`, but in `org`'s source code, I cannot found this function. What is its definition?

Comment: It is in `org.el`, at least in org version 9.4.6.

Comment: Please relate the question to its title. Are you asking about the error message or asking whether that symbol is defined in Org, or what?